# Meaning of zeros in TF-IDF matrix summed over columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, numpy, python-3.7

I created a TF-IDF scores matrix for a collection of documents and provided a vocabulary for the same, using scikit-learn's TFIDFVectorizer. Since I wanted the most important words throughout the corpus, I summed up the values by column - that is, summed the TF-IDF values for each word across all the documents. What does it mean when this sum is 0 for certain words? The vocabulary is derived from the documents only, so it is not that they're out of the documents or something.

Comment: pls show us you data and code. Thanks.

Comment: Hello, Did you get solution for the same ?